# Convert all file extensions to lower-case

Tags: linux, bash, file-extension

I'm trying to lower-case all my extensions regardless of what it is. So far, from what I've seen, you have to specify what file extensions you want to convert to lower-case. However, I just want to lower-case everything after the <s>first</s> last dot `.` in the name.

How can I do that in `bash`?

Comment: The asker has another question recently about a bash script to rename files. So he might be asking how to write a bash script that changes the name of every file (in his home directory? in and under a directory? just in a directory?) to change each uppercase letter in the filename’s extension to lowercase, except for the first letter. E.g., “PICTURE.JPG” would be renamed to “PICTURE.Jpg”.

Comment: I have files that ends in testing.mP3 testing.Mp3 - I want to rename all to *.mp3

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**Solution**

You can solve the task in one line:

```
find . -name '*.*' -exec sh -c '
  a=$(echo "$0" | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/");
  [ "$a" != "$0" ] && mv "$0" "$a" ' {} \;
```

Note: this will break for filenames that contain newlines. But bear with me for now.

**Example of usage**

```
$ mkdir C; touch 1.TXT a.TXT B.TXT C/D.TXT
$ find .
.
./C
./C/D.TXT
./1.TXT
./a.TXT
./B.TXT

$ find . -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'a=$(echo "$0" | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/"); [ "$a" != "$0" ] && mv "$0" "$a" ' {} \;

$ find .
.
./C
./C/D.txt
./a.txt
./B.txt
./1.txt
```

**Explanation**

You find all files in current directory (`.`) that have period `.` in its name (`-name '*.*'`) and run the command for each file:

```
a=$(echo "$0" | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/");
[ "$a" != "$0" ] && mv "{}" "$a"
```

That command means: try to convert file extension to lowercase (that makes `sed`):

```
$ echo 1.txt | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/"
1.txt
$ echo 2.TXT | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/"
2.txt
```

and save the result to the `a` variable.

If something was changed `[ "$a" != "$0" ]`, rename the file `mv "$0" "$a"`.

The name of the file being processed (`{}`) passed to `sh -c` as its additional argument and it is seen inside the command line as `$0`.
It makes the script safe, because in this case the shell take {} as a data, not as a code-part, as when it is specified directly in the command line. 
(*I thank* @gniourf_gniourf *for pointing me at this really important issue*).

As you can see, if you use `{}` directly in the script,
it's possible to have 
some shell-injections in the filenames, something like:

```
; rm -rf * ;
```

In this case the injection will be considered by the shell as a part of 
the code and they will be executed.

**While-version**

Clearer, but a little bit longer, version of the script:

```
find . -name '*.*' | while IFS= read -r f
do
  a=$(echo "$f" | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/");
  [ "$a" != "$f" ] && mv "$f" "$a"
done
```

This still breaks for filenames containing newlines. To fix this issue, you need to have a `find` that supports `-print0` (like GNU `find`) and Bash (so that `read` supports the `-d` delimiter switch):

```
find . -name '*.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f
do
  a=$(echo "$f" | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/");
  [ "$a" != "$f" ] && mv "$f" "$a"
done
```

This still breaks for files that contain trailing newlines (as they will be absorbed by the `a=$(...)` subshell. If you *really* want a foolproof method (and you should!), with a recent version of Bash (Bash≥4.0) that supports the `,,` parameter expansion here's the ultimate solution:

```
find . -name '*.*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f
do
  base=${f%.*}
  ext=${f##*.}
  a=$base.${ext,,}
  [ "$a" != "$f" ] && mv -- "$f" "$a"
done
```

**Back to the original solution**

Or in one `find` go (back to the original solution with some fixes that makes it really foolproof):

```
find . -name '*.*' -type f -exec bash -c 'base=${0%.*} ext=${0##*.} a=$base.${ext,,}; [ "$a" != "$0" ] && mv -- "$0" "$a"' {} \;
```

I added `-type f` so that only regular files are renamed. Without this, you could still have problems if directory names are renamed before file names. If you also want to rename directories (and links, pipes, etc.) you should use `-depth`:

```
find . -depth -name '*.*' -type f -exec bash -c 'base=${0%.*} ext=${0##*.} a=$base.${ext,,}; [ "$a" != "$0" ] && mv -- "$0" "$a"' {} \;
```

so that `find` performs a depth-first search.

You may argue that it's not efficient to spawn a `bash` process for each file found. That's correct, and the previous loop version would then be better.

Comment: Although your script is very clever, I think you miss the case when there's a `'` in the directory/file name

Comment: I think the same issue applies for the round brackets: `(` and `)`

Comment: Macs [ship with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298356/sed-and-mac-os-x-differences-with-to-upper-to-lower-and-whole-capture-control-s) BSD `sed`, not GNU `sed`, unfortunately, and only the latter supports the [lowercasing](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) `\L` sequence. Mac users with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) can `brew install gnu-sed` and run your shell command with `gsed` replacing `sed`.

Comment: awesome, +1, worked perfectly in GIT BASH on windows

Comment: How about the names with space or special char; such as 10-14-2011 8;43;24 PM.JPG?

Comment: @lidt: Spaces and all special characters (except a couple) are supported

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: sh -c is always dangerous, that's just obvious what yoi've said

Comment: @IgorChubin No, `sh -c` is safe if used properly. The this is that with the way you're using `{}`, it's very easy to forge filenames that will end up having horrible consequences. If you say that what I said is obvious, it means you didn't understand what I mean.

Comment: You should use `{}` as an argument (as data), not as code (like you did): `-exec sh -c ' ...stuff... ' {} \;` where stuff uses the 0-th positional parameter when it needs filename, e.g., `-exec sh -c 'a=$(echo "$0" | sed -r "s/([^.]*)\$/\L\1/"); [ "$a" != "$0" ] && mv "$0" "$a" ' {} \;`. Like so, you're sure that the argument (data) will always be properly used as data and not potentially as code. With this method there are no ways to inject code.

Comment: By the way, your _safe_ version is broken for filename containing trailing spaces, backslashes or newlines and there are errors since you didn't replace `{}` with `$f`, and your `echo $f` is not properly quoted

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Very good tip! (I mean the trick with "$0" and {}). Thank you for it. It's really cool

Comment: Two other similar tricks: sometimes you don't want to use `$0` but `$1` instead (maybe because you're copying and pasting some other one-liner or function you already have). In this case: `-exec sh -c '... stuff with "$1" ...' _ {} \;`. Here `_` plays the role of a dummy argument (it could be anything else), and `"$1"` is the properly and safely quoted expansion of the filename. Next trick: when using `-exec ... +`: use this: `-exec sh -c 'for i; do ... stuff with $i ...; done' _ {} +`. Here you really need to add a dummy argument.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thank you very much for the explanation, for the comments and for the -1 (I suppose it was also from you, but it was absolutely fair). The question is really popular and beloved from the search machines, so it's really important that the answer is correct and doesn't contain such wrong advices/ideas/technics. I think that with your tips this answer (I edited it and added you suggestions) become much more useful. Thank you very much once again!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Thank you! We can make the answer better still (if you have any new suggestions) and after that you can even give it +1 :)

Comment: @IgorChubin All right. I fixed a few typos you had (can't remember which ones now...). I feel that the answer is slightly messier than before, so now you have some work to do to improve it further with the suggestions I added. There's still one thing I'm concerned with (as explained in the versions at the bottom): either use `-type f` or `-depth`, otherwise you'll get errors when the directory is renamed before its content. If you don't like my edit, just rollback (yet, try to keep the typo fixes if you can). Good luck `:)`.

Comment: And it would be wonderful to explicit which version is POSIX (i.e., relatively portable) and the ones that use GNU-isms and bashisms... well, there's still some work to do to have a beautiful answer that will be _the ultimate answer_.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I checked your comments/fixes. They are really perfect!! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: The question doesn't ask for it, but on Mac you can [wrap a version of this in Automator](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ltcul.png) and save it as a Service, which lets you [right click on files](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VkgJw.png) and lowercase their extensions.

Answer (score 61):

I got success with this command.

```
rename JPG jpg *.JPG
```

Where `rename` is a command that tells the shell to rename every occurrence of `JPG` to `jpg` in the current folder with all filenames having extension `JPG`.

If you see Bareword "JPG" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1 with this approach try:

```
rename 's/\.JPG$/.jpg/' *.JPG
```

Comment: On a mac, `brew install rename` works, but since it's a case-insenstitive filesystem you have to rename to `jpg_` and then perform another rename from `jpg_` back to `jpg`.

Comment: I like this answer. Just a simple regex match and replace, which is versatile for other situations using the rename command. Use the -n switch to do a "dry run" first in case you've made a mistake.

Comment: `rename` is the name for the package on Debian systems.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not properly address the question: "Convert **all** file extensions to lower-case" (emphasis mine). With your solution, one has to run the command once for all possible extensions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32729737/735926) is better in this regard.

Answer (score 18):

This is shorter but more general, combined from other's answer:

```
rename 's/\.([^.]+)$/.\L$1/' *
```

**Simulation**

For simulation, use `-n`, i.e. `rename -n 's/\.([^.]+)$/.\L$1/' *`. This way you can see what will be changed before the real changes being performed. Example output:

```
Happy.Family.GATHERING.JPG renamed as Happy.Family.GATHERING.jpg
Hero_from_The_Land_Across_the_River.JPG renamed as Hero_from_The_Land_Across_the_River.jpg
rAnD0m.jPg1 renamed as rAnD0m.jpg1
```

**Short explanation about the syntax**

- The syntax is `rename OPTIONS 's/WHAT_TO_FIND_IN_THE_NAME/THE_REPLACEMENT/' FILENAMES`
- `\.([^.]+)$` means sequence of anything but dot (`[^.]`) at the end of the string (`$`), after dot (`\.`)
- `.\L$1` means dot (`\.`) followed by lowercase (`\L`) of 1<sup>st</sup> group (`$1`)
- First group in this case is the extension (`[^.]+`)
- You better use single quote `'` instead of double quote `"` to wrap the regex to avoid shell expansion

Comment: I would say this is the best answer, regarding that it is short and elegant, and actually answers the question (compared to other answers that are higher voted)! Probably came to late...

Comment: Best answer in my opinion, and here's my one liner to rename all files with lowercase extension: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rename 's/\.([^.]+)$/.\L$1/gi' "{}"`

Comment: For anyone having the same issue as me: to change this to upper case, use `\U` instead of `\L`.

Answer (score 11):

Well, you could use this snippet as the core of whatever alternative you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

# lowerext.sh    

while read f; do
    if [[ "$f" = *.* ]]; then
        # Extract the basename
        b="${f%.*}"

        # Extract the extension
        x="${f##*.}"

        # Convert the extension to lower case
        # Note: this only works in recent versions of Bash
        l="${x,,}"

        if [[ "$x" != "$l" ]]; then
            mv "$f" "$b.$l"
        fi
    else
        continue
    fi
done
```

Afterwards, all you need to do is feed a list of the files you need to rename to its standard input. E.g. for all files under the current directory and any subdirectory:

```
find -type f | lowerext.sh
```

A small optimization:

```
find -type f -name '*.*' | lowerext.sh
```

You will have to be more specific if you need a more concrete answer than this...

Comment: I often dd for case conversion in scripts. lower=$( echo "FOO" | dd conv=lcase )

Comment: @Adam: `tr '[:ucase:]' '[:lcase:]'` also works, but using command substitution of any kind launches at least one new process per case conversion...

Comment: Note that on a case-insensitive file-system (such as found by default on Mac OS X), you cannot simply rename files like this: trying `mv xx.YY xx.yy` generates `mv: 'xx.YY' and 'xx.yy' are the same file`.  (You have to do it in two steps, such as: `mv xx.YY xx.YY.$$; mv xx.YY.$$ xx.yy`.)  However, since the tag is `linux`, this solution is fine.

Comment: @thkala I'm well aware of new processes/performance issues, I only provided comment as your answer stated it only worked in recent versions of bash.

Comment: You can do almost the same but in a oneliner (of course it would be not so beautiful anymore :). Please review my answer :)

Comment: This is broken for filenames containing newlines or backslashes. The latter can be fixed by using the `-r` switch to `read`. For the former, you need a `find` that supports `-print0`, use it, and modify your `read` statement like so: `IFS= read -r -d '' f`.

Comment: if you have older version of bash, you can use the typeset command (available for bash version 2 and older) the script will be `#!/bin/bash

# lowerext.sh    

while read f; do
    if [[ "$f" = *.* ]]; then
        # Extract the basename
        b="${f%.*}"

        # Extract the extension
        x="${f##*.}"

        # Convert the extension to lower case
        # for bash version > 2
        typeset -l l=$x

        if [[ "$x" != "$l" ]]; then
            mv "$f" "$b.$l"
        fi
    else
        continue
    fi
done
`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using ZSH:

```
zmv '(*).(*)' '$1.$2:l'
```

If you get `zsh: command not found: zmv` then simply run:

```
autoload -U zmv
```

And then try again.

Thanks to this [original article](https://coderwall.com/p/yepegw/mass-renaming-files-with-zmv-zsh) for the tip about zmv and the [ZSH documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_12.html) for the lowercase/uppercase substitution syntax.

Comment: alternatively, `zmv -v '(*)' '${(L)f:gs/ /_/}'` will substitute spaces with underscores and lowercase the names for all files (displaying changes on screen)

Comment: bang on the money for me on macOS :)

Answer (score 5):

This will do the job for your '.mp3's - but only in the working directory - however is able to consume filenames with whitespace:

```
for f in *.[mM][pP]3; do mv "$f" "${f%.*}.mp3"; done
```

Correction:

```
for f in *.[mM][pP]3; do [[ "$f" =~ \.mp3$ ]] || mv "$f" "${f%.*}.mp3"; done
```

Comment: This runs into problems if you have any files that already have the correct `.mp3` extension — `mv` will indicate an error because the two files are the same.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I saw that but thought it would work - Now I learn that it doesn't - Thanks. I'll fix it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

recursively for all one fine solution:

```
find -name '*.JPG' | sed 's/\(.*\)\.JPG/mv "\1.JPG" "\1.jpg"/' |sh
```

The above recursively renames files with the extension "JPG" to files with the extension "jpg"

Comment: This is very bad and broken. Do not use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `mmv` (=move multiple files) installed and your filenames contain at most one dot, you can use

```
mmv -v "*.*" "#1.#l2"
```

It does not get more than one dot right (since the matching algo for `*` is not greedy in `mmv`), however, it handles `()` and `'` correctly. Example:

```
$ mmv -v "*.*" "#1.#l2"
FOO.BAR.MP3 -> FOO.bar.mp3 : done
foo bar 'baz' (CD 1).MP3 -> foo bar 'baz' (CD 1).mp3 : done
```

Not perfect, but much easier to use and remember than all the `find/exec/sed` stuff.

Comment: `mmv` is a great tool, it's just good to know it touches the __ctimes__ of __all files matching the from pattern__, i.e. files listed with the -n and -v options, irrespective of whether they are renamed or not

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a simple way to do this (without having to think about it) but I finally ended up thinking it through and came up with this (admittedly, way after the original post)

```
find . -name \\*.JPG -print -exec rename s/.JPG/.jpg/ {} \\;
```

I ran it on about 60 thousand files and it worked fine but, of course, you can use the `-n` option to 'rename' if you want to test it out first.

Comment: >>find: missing argument to `-exec'

Answer (score 0):

So, these solutions that look like line noise are nice and all, but this is easy to do from the python REPL (I know the OP asked for bash, but python is installed on a lot of systems that have bash these days...):

```
import os
files = os.listdir('.')
for f in files:
    path, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    if ext.isupper():
        os.rename(f, path + ext.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only interested in certain file extensions like converting all higher case "JPG" extensions to lower case "jpg" You could use the command line utility **rename** like so. CD into directory you want to change. Then

```
rename -n 's/\.JPG$/\.jpg/' *
```

Use -n option to test what will be changed, then when you happy with results use without like so

```
rename  's/\.JPG$/\.jpg/' *
```

Answer (score 0):

My small and primitive script to convert extensions to lowercase recursively:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# find files with at least one uppercase character in an extension in the input directory recursively and optionally convert extensions to lowercase

# usage:
# find_file_extensions_with_uppercase_chars dir [convert]

dir=$1
[[ -z $1 ]] && dir=.

shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar extglob
for file in "$dir"/**/*; do
    if [[ ! -d $file ]]; then
        filename=${file##*/}
        if [[ $filename =~ \. ]]; then
            ext="${filename#*.}"
            if [[ $ext =~ [[:upper:]] ]]; then
                file="${file//+(\/)/\/}"
                echo $file
                if [[ -n $2 ]]; then
                    ext_length=${#ext}
                    conv_file=${file::((-ext_length))}${ext,,}
                    mv -iv "$file" "$conv_file"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

Here, an extension is a string after the **first** dot in the filename, if you want it to be a string after the **last** dot in the filename (as you've asked), just change `ext="${filename#*.}"` to `ext="${filename##*.}"`.