# sed and Mac OS X differences with to upper, to lower and whole capture control sequences

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I am trying to take the last two letters out of a filename which are uppercase and append them to the filename in lowercase. I expeceted the command:

```sh
ls | sed -e "s/.*\([A-Z][A-Z]\)$/\0\/\L\1\E/"
```

to achieve this and on my Ubuntu box it worked fine but on my Mac it simply prints out a `0/LXXE/` where `XX` are the correct letters from the capture.

What are the Mac sed equivalents of `\0`, `\L` and `\E`?

I've had a look around the web and several people have noticed that Mac OS X sed is different from Ubuntu sed but most threads talk about the `-i` requirement for a file extension or empty string (which has previously tripped me up).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OSX (BSD) sed doesn't support functions `\L`, `\E` etc. Install `gnu sed` on Mac using this option:

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Comment: `brew install --default-names gnu-sed` to install as `sed` instead of `gsed`

Comment: "Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported."

Comment: OSX sed is not an older version, it's the BSD version.

Comment: Thanks @DanielC.Sobral, I will reword my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` alternative:

```sh
ls | awk '{print $0 tolower(substr($0,length($0)-1,2))}'
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as required (on OS X at least) - the last two characters are repeated.

Comment: @PaulR: As far as I understood, that's what the OP wanted: '*...take the last two letters [...] and append them...*'. If you want to *replace* the last two characters by their lower case versions, try this: `ls | awk '{print substr($0,1,length($0)-2) tolower(substr($0,length($0)-1,2))}'`