# Allow for case-sensitivity in <img tag from PHP Variable & file extension

Tags: php

I built a PHP script that dynamically generates & displays an IMG tag like this:

```
<img src=/img/{$row['Invl_InventoryNumber']}.BMP>
```

This worked great on a Windows server where case-sensitivity was not an issue.

We moved the script to Linux and have found that the files have both .BMP and .bmp file extensions AND ALSO the $row['Invl_InventoryNumber] variable contains Alphabetical values that are uppercase too.

Example: RZP.bmp OR rzp.bmp OR RZP.BMP OR RzP.bmp OR Rzp.BMP etc, etc.

I have no control over the naming scheme of the files, they are created by a human but need to account/look for matching files names.  I was thinking of some sort of CASE or if/elseif statement but was not sure if there is a better way to trigger the value to check all possibilities.

Comment: the better way is to code everything (vars, function names, files etc. etc.) in camelCase - this ensures no matter what env you're in that it will work

Comment: Can you not store the filename in the database, rather than just guessing what the file name might be?

Comment: Since you've moved to Linux you could use a quick script to change the file extensions is easy enough. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818408/convert-all-file-extensions-to-lower-case

Comment: define a pattern, ex: set all filenames to lowercase both in server and db

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the some Unix OS;

So I suggest that you standardize your files or save the same name (with cappitalized when there are) in your database.

However, you can try to use ["mod_speling"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html) if you to serve your pages with Apache.