# How to exclude new lines (carriage returns) using find regex on GNU/Linux cli?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I'm trying to rename all files in a directory with de JPG extension to lowercase jpg.
I've made this bash code with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818408/convert-all-file-extensions-to-lower-case):

```
find . -regex ".*\.JPG" -exec sh -c 'echo "$0" | sed -r "s/\.JPG/\.jpg/" && mv "$0" "$1"' {} \;
```

But I get the following error:

```
./IMG_1352.jpg
mv: cannot move './IMG_1352.JPG' to '': No such file or directory
(and so on...)
```

I think I need to change names "places" but I don't know how.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you have `\r`'s? in your filenames?

Comment: As you can see in my post, the $1 variable is empty.  $0 gets the value of the found file {}, but there is no $1 parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR:  Try this code:

```
find . -name '*.JPG' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv $0  ${0/.JPG/.jpg}' {}  \;
```

More commentary:

Your code is pretty close to where it needs to be.  There is an issue, however, in as much as $1 is not defined.

I ran the following code to figure out what value was going to be in $1.

```
$ ls
bye.jpg hi.JPG
$ find . -regex ".*\.JPG" -exec sh -c 'echo "$0" | sed  "s/\.JPG/\.jpg/" && echo "0:$0 1:$1" ' {} \;
./hi.jpg
0:./hi.JPG 1:
```

According to my results above, there is *no* value in $1.   You should be aware that $1 actually refers to the second parameter passed to the sh.  That is,  sh -c 'code' $0 $1 ...

Anyway, you'll need to capture the result of the sed command in a variable to pass it to the move command as follows:

```
find . -regex ".*\.JPG" -exec sh -c '
    lower=$( echo "$0" | sed -r "s/\.JPG/\.jpg/" )
    mv "$0" "$lower"
' {}  \;
```

All that said, you could make this more concise.  As PS suggests, the for loop is a good choice.  Also, the JPG -> jpb replacement is more readable with PS's suggestion.  If you are sold on using find, you can incorporate PS's suggestion as follows:

```
find . -regex ".*\.JPG" -exec sh -c '
    filename=$0
    mv "$filename" "${filename/.JPG/.jpg}"
' {}  \;
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark, your solution worked like a charm! But I have a question: is it mandatory to use brackets in `${0/.JPG/.jpg}'` or one can use '$(0/.JPG/.jpg)'`?

Comment: @Damon - ${0/.JPG/.jpg} is the way to go - the $() syntax, that is with parens, tells the shell to execute the commands - AFAIK $() is the equivalent to ``.