# ZSH: rename files in nested folders, capitalize specific letters

Tags: terminal, rename, zsh

I have many nested folders of json language files, such as

```
da-dk.json
de-de.json
en-us.json
```

I need to change them all to capitalize the letters after the hyphen, as in

```
da-DK.json
de-DE.json
en-US.json
```

I am on a Mac with zsh.  I originally thought I could do it with a GUI utility I have used called A Better Finder Rename but it apparently  does not offer case conversions on replace.

I know regex and figured it would be something like find
`^([a-z]{2})-([a-z]{2})` and replace with `$1-\U$2` but I'm not sure how to do this in the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are using ZSH shell, you can use the awesome `zmv` command

```
zmv '(**/)(*)-(*).json' '${1}${2}-$3:u.json'
```

You may need to `autoload zmv` before running the above command.

Short explanation:

- `(**/)` takes care of nested folders which is mapped to `${1}`
- First `(*)` matches the part before hyphen and is mapped to `${2}`
- Second `(*)` matches the part after hyphen and is uppercased by `:u` before being mapped to `${3}`.

There are some useful material in [this SO question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11818408/6560462).

Answer (score 1):

In traditional shell commands:

```
for i in *.json; do
    echo mv "$i" "${i:0:3}$(tr '[[:lower:]]' '[[:upper:]]' <<< ${i:3:2}).json"
done
```

Drop `echo` when the output looks good.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl rename](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/rename):

install via homebrew (if not already installed):

```
brew install rename
```

command:

```
rename -n 's/\w{2}(?=\.)/uc $&/e' *.json
```

Drop `-n` switch when the output looks good.

Comment: I had to add a glob path and use `-f` since I guess on Mac it's case-insensitive and thought the files already existed, so I used `rename -n -f 's/\w{2}(?=\.)/uc $&/e' **/*.json`